# Dserialise JSON to object. Some properties always the same, some different

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to build a function where a user can upload a json file.

Each row in the json file can have a different nr of properties(i.e. columns).
5 of these properties are always the same so I want those to be deserialized to an object. The rest of the properties have to go into a dictionary or something.

Here is a json example:

```
[{
        "Projekt": "Bakker Bouw Service",
        "Ruimte": "Hoofdgebouw",
        "Apparaat": {
            "project": "Bosboom001",
            "versie": "812"
        },
        "Apparaat naam": "",
        "Status": "Goedgekeurd",
        "Testname1": "",
        "Testname3": "2000-01-04T10:37:00+01:00",
        "Testname7": "2001-01-03T00:00:00+01:00"
    }, {
        "Projekt": "Bakker Bouw Service",
        "Ruimte": "Hoofdgebouw",
        "Apparaat": {
            "project": "Vlaams003",
            "versie": "713"
        },
        "Apparaat naam": "",
        "Status": "Goedgekeurd",
        "Testname1": "Slecht",
        "Testname7": "2000-01-04T10:37:00+01:00",
        "Testname9": "2001-01-03T00:00:00+01:00",
        "Testname16": "18MOhm",
        "Testname23": "OK"
    }, {
        "Projekt": "Bakker Bouw Service",
        "Ruimte": "Hoofdgebouw",
        "Apparaat": {
            "project": "Vlaams017",
            "versie": "73"
        },
        "Apparaat naam": "GDR34Z5",
        "Status": "Afgekeurd",
        "Testname7": "2000-01-04T10:37:00+01:00",
        "Testname10": "0,012mA",
        "Testname16": "200MOhm",
        "Testname23": "200MOhm",
        "Testname25": "Afgekeurd",
        "Testname31": "0,01mA"
    }
]
```

Here is the class to deserialze to:

```
public class KeuringRegel
{
    public string Projekt { get; set; }
    public string Ruimte { get; set; }
    public Apparaat Apparaat { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Apparaat naam")]
    public string Apparaatnaam { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> testNames { get; set; }
}

public class Apparaat
{
    public string project { get; set; }
    public string versie { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the controller

```
public IActionResult Upload(IFormFile file)
    {
        string fileContent = null;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
        {
            fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        List<KeuringRegel> keuringRegelList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeuringRegel>>(fileContent);
        //More stuff here
    }
```

The json successfully deserializes but the `testNames` value is always null. I understand why, because there is no `testNames` property in the Json file. However, how do I achieve what I want? I am no Json expert.

Comment: Where is this JSON built ?

Comment: https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer

Comment: They probably meant to ask whether you can change the format of the JSON, or have to parse it as-is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you can do this, assuming that there is *only* `testNameNNNN` entries as supplemental values, is to use the [`JsonExtensionDataAttribute`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonExtensionDataAttribute.cs) like this:

```
public class KeuringRegel
{
    public string Projekt { get; set; }
    public string Ruimte { get; set; }
    public Apparaat Apparaat { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Apparaat naam")]
    public string Apparaatnaam { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [JsonExtensionData()]
    public Dictionary<string, object> testNames { get; set; }
}
```

This will give you the values whos don't fall into one of the other properties:

[image]

It's a bit of a "blunt instrument" but you could always perform some post-processing on the returned instances of `KeuringRegel` to remove any errant entries from testNames (i.e. things that don't match the pattern `testNameNNNN`).

If your JSON *does* contain things that don't match the pattern `testNameNNNN` which would therefore get included, you could implement a custom class for the `testNames` property:

```
public class KeuringRegel
{
    public string Projekt { get; set; }
    public string Ruimte { get; set; }
    public Apparaat Apparaat { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Apparaat naam")]
    public string Apparaatnaam { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [JsonExtensionData()]
    public TestNames testNames { get; set; }
}

public class TestNames : Dictionary<string, object>
{
    public new void Add(string key, object value)
    {
        if (key.StartsWith("testname", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            base.Add(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

This will check each item that is added to the `testNames` dictionary and prevent its addition if (as in my comment where I had an item in the JSON of `"badgerBadgetCatCat":  3`) it doesn't match the pattern.

Comment: I was looking into a custom JsonConverter, but quickly gave up. This is the most pragmatic solution. JSON.NET will deserialize from class properties, not from the JSON, so the converter will never see the `TestnameNNN` tokens anyway.

Comment: Excellent solution! Thanks! Are there any pros and cons about this solution. Is it the recommended way of doing things? Is it better to change the JSON-format?  Maybe a link to a good example doc or something

Comment: @Kipei obviously the sensible thing to do would be to properly format the JSON where it's generated. Numbered properties are a hallmark of bad design.

Comment: @Kipei, as @CodeCaster says, it's a pragmatic solution, so you will get other stuff in the dictionary (e.g. if the JSON ends up with something like `"badgerBadgetCatCat": 3` in it). In an ideal world you'd change the JSON format, but if the format of the JSON is static, you're good to go.

Comment: @Kipei, I've just added a suggestion to the body of the answer that would help to make the code more robust in the face of the content of the JSON changing after you've written your code. Something that you should perhaps consider for code resiliency =)

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you. The `testNames` properties are not really numbered. They have names like "leakage current", "protection line" and "max voltage". 1 json row can have these 3 props, the next can have 2 more and no "protection line", for example. I check all the property names in the `testNames` dict for each row and compare if they exists in the db. If the prop does not exists the user get's an error with a message to first create the testname in the db.

Comment: @Kipei, I've just blogged an example of another way to do this (http://robertwray.co.uk/blog/deserializing-awkward-json-using-json-net) if this is something that suits better, let me know and I'll update the answer with it =)

Comment: Very interesting article Rob! As I said, I am no json expert. The coming days I am very busy trying to get something to work. There for, next week I will definitly take a closer look at it and start "exampling" with it myself and comment about it

Answer (score 0):

Here u are full example

```
internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var str = @"[{
        ""Projekt"": ""Bakker Bouw Service"",
        ""Ruimte"": ""Hoofdgebouw"",
        ""Apparaat"": {
            ""project"": ""Bosboom001"",
            ""versie"": ""812""
        },
        ""Apparaat naam"": """",
        ""Status"": ""Goedgekeurd"",
        ""Testname1"": """",
        ""Testname3"": ""2000-01-04T10:37:00+01:00"",
        ""Testname7"": ""2001-01-03T00:00:00+01:00""
    }, {
        ""Projekt"": ""Bakker Bouw Service"",
        ""Ruimte"": ""Hoofdgebouw"",
        ""Apparaat"": {
            ""project"": ""Vlaams003"",
            ""versie"": ""713""
        },
        ""Apparaat naam"": """",
        ""Status"": ""Goedgekeurd"",
        ""Testname1"": ""Slecht"",
        ""Testname7"": ""2000-01-04T10:37:00+01:00"",
        ""Testname9"": ""2001-01-03T00:00:00+01:00"",
        ""Testname16"": ""18MOhm"",
        ""Testname23"": ""OK""
    }, {
        ""Projekt"": ""Bakker Bouw Service"",
        ""Ruimte"": ""Hoofdgebouw"",
        ""Apparaat"": {
            ""project"": ""Vlaams017"",
            ""versie"": ""73""
        },
        ""Apparaat naam"": ""GDR34Z5"",
        ""Status"": ""Afgekeurd"",
        ""Testname7"": ""2000-01-04T10:37:00+01:00"",
        ""Testname10"": ""0,012mA"",
        ""Testname16"": ""200MOhm"",
        ""Testname23"": ""200MOhm"",
        ""Testname25"": ""Afgekeurd"",
        ""Testname31"": ""0,01mA""
    }
]";

            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            var result = Mapper.Map(str);


            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Deserialized at {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms ({sw.ElapsedTicks} tiks)");
        }

        public static class Mapper
        {
            static Mapper()
            {
                List<string> names = new List<string>();
                IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> p = typeof(KeuringRegel).GetProperties().Where(c => c.CanRead && c.CanWrite);
                foreach (var propertyInfo in p)
                {
                    var attr = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>();
                    names.Add(attr != null ? attr.PropertyName : propertyInfo.Name);
                }

                Properties = names.ToArray();
            }


            private static string[] Properties { get; }



            public static KeuringRegel[] Map(string str)
            {
                var keuringRegels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KeuringRegel[]>(str);
                var objs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str) as IEnumerable;
                var objectList = new List<JObject>();
                foreach (JObject obj in objs)
                    objectList.Add(obj);

                for (var i = 0; i < keuringRegels.Length; i++)
                {
                    keuringRegels[i].testNames = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    foreach (var p in objectList[i].Children().OfType<JProperty>().Where(c => !Properties.Contains(c.Name)).ToArray())
                        keuringRegels[i].testNames.Add(p.Name, p.Value);
                }

                return keuringRegels;
            }
        }


        public class KeuringRegel
        {
            public string Projekt { get; set; }
            public string Ruimte { get; set; }
            public Apparaat Apparaat { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Apparaat naam")]
            public string Apparaatnaam { get; set; }

            public string Status { get; set; }
            public Dictionary<string, object> testNames { get; set; }
        }

        public class Apparaat
        {
            public string project { get; set; }
            public string versie { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please explain your approach.